# Is it possible to get v8 to internally inline a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, v8

I'm wondering if there is any way to get v8 to internally inline a function to speed up overall execution.

I have a simple function that returns the total energy of a pixel:

```
function pxEnergy(x, y) {
  var tmp = (y * cols + x - 1) * 4
  return (data[tmp] + data[tmp + 1] + data[tmp + 2]) * data[tmp + 3];
}
```

I'm calling this ~96,000,000 times and my code takes ~2 sec to run.

If I inline the function 8 times in my loops, e.g.:

```
xSum += -2 * (tmp = (y * cols + x - 1) * 4, (data[tmp] + data[tmp + 1] + data[tmp + 2]) * data[tmp + 3]);
```

The same code now takes ~500ms to run.  But it's ugly as sin :)

So I'm wondering if anyone has any magic tricks up their sleeves to get the same speedup without manually inlining the function.

[edit] full code per request:

```
generateEnergyMap() {
  // woo-hoo, nothing to do!
  if (!this.dirty) { return Promise.resolve(); }

  var energyMap = this.energyMap = [];
  var cols      = this.width;
  var rows      = this.height;
  var data      = this.data;

  var pxEnergy = new Function('data', 'cols', 'x', 'y', 'var ix = (y * cols + x) * 4; return (data[ix] + data[ix + 1] + data[ix + 2]) * data[ix + 3]');

  return this.imgPromise.then(function() {
    for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
      energyMap.push([]);

      for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
        var up    = y;
        var down  = y < (rows - 1);
        var left  = x;
        var right = x < (cols - 1);
        var tmp;

        var xSum = 0;
        var ySum = 0;

        if (left) {
          xSum += -2 * pxEnergy(data, cols, x - 1, y); // (tmp = (y * cols + x - 1) * 4, (data[tmp] + data[tmp + 1] + data[tmp + 2]) * data[tmp + 3]);

          if (up) {
            xSum += tmp = -1 * pxEnergy(data, cols, x - 1, y - 1); // (tmp = ((y - 1) * cols + x - 1) * 4, (data[tmp] + data[tmp + 1] + data[tmp + 2]) * data[tmp + 3]);
            ySum += tmp;
          }

          if (down) {
            xSum += -1 * (tmp = pxEnergy(data, cols, x - 1, y + 1)); // (tmp = (tmp = ((y + 1) * cols + x - 1) * 4, (data[tmp] + data[tmp + 1] + data[tmp + 2]) * data[tmp + 3]));
            ySum += tmp;
          }
        }

        if (right) {
          xSum += 2 * pxEnergy(data, cols, x + 1, y); // (tmp = (y * cols + x + 1) * 4, (data[tmp] + data[tmp + 1] + data[tmp + 2]) * data[tmp + 3]);

          if (up) {
            xSum += tmp = pxEnergy(data, cols, x + 1, y - 1); // (tmp = ((y - 1) * cols + x + 1) * 4, (data[tmp] + data[tmp + 1] + data[tmp + 2]) * data[tmp + 3]);
            ySum += -1 * tmp;
          }

          if (down) {
            xSum += tmp = pxEnergy(data, cols, x + 1, y + 1); // (tmp = ((y + 1) * cols + x + 1) * 4, (data[tmp] + data[tmp + 1] + data[tmp + 2]) * data[tmp + 3]);
            ySum += tmp;
          }
        }

        if (up) {
          ySum += -2 * pxEnergy(data, cols, x, y - 1); // (tmp = ((y - 1) * cols + x) * 4, (data[tmp] + data[tmp + 1] + data[tmp + 2]) * data[tmp + 3]);
        }

        if (down) {
          ySum += 2 * pxEnergy(data, cols, x, y + 1); // (tmp = ((y + 1) * cols + x) * 4, (data[tmp] + data[tmp + 1] + data[tmp + 2]) * data[tmp + 3]);
        }

         energyMap[y].push(Math.sqrt(xSum * xSum + ySum * ySum));
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: passing `data` and `cols` to the function should help, if the function is defined only once and re-used 96k times... making it pure and generic and in a high scope allows caching and helps in-lining.

Comment: @dandavis -- I tried that, it shaves the total time from ~2s to ~1.7s.  Nowhere near the same results :(  Removing the closure entirely (via `new Function(...)` brought it to ~1.5 sec)

Comment: Well, there is a minimum function call overhead, and it won't get better than that. Even though it won't work, you can test the time it takes with a noop or `Boolean` or something equally fast, and that will be the best you can accomplish without the ugly code. if that's still 1.5 seconds, go with ugly.

Comment: @dandavis -- Adding 8 calls to a noop fn pushes it to ~600ms.  I've no idea if it's just getting optimized out though.  I know there's a minimum function call overhead, hence the title of the question :)

Comment: Can you post the whole code? With out seeing the full code (or at least the function your are calling it from) it's impossible to say why it is not inlined in the first place. Most probably V8 just runs out of inlining budget - in which case there is nothing you can do.

Comment: there are additional command-line flags to use with node specifically for getting info about optimization. for example, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/#toc-topic-compilation (scroll down slightly)

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov -- Updated with code

Comment: why the `new Function` instead of a "real" function ? that won't optimize very well...

Comment: @dandavis -- It's faster :)  The short of it is that it "removes" the closure stack from the function.  It runs ~10% faster in this case than the exact same "real" function

Comment: what are the width and height? I run the code with 100 and 100 and every instance of pxEnergy is inlined. Though I can imagine cases when this is not the case.

Comment: also I suggest replacing energyMap[y].push() with using Float64Array of the preallocate size (rows * cols) potentially.

Comment: last idea: you might try declaring x+y above the loops, then hard-coding the pxEnergy() function, and not passing any args to the function, using closure only. i can see where closure+passing is slower (more overhead), but maybe just closure alone would be faster...

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov - ~4000x3000.  How do you know they're inlined?  And yes, I intend to optimize the array types and declarations, but one step at a time :)

Comment: no, passing arguments explicitly is preferred to passing arguments through the context - because passing arguments through the context creates unnecessary memory traffic - and as such you need to rely on store-to-load forwarding optimization, which is not powerful enough in V8 to completely eliminate redundant memory traffic in this case

Comment: @zyklus I use http://mrale.ph/irhydra/2 to see if they are inlined or not. alternatively you can just read `--trace-inlining`. In IRHydra you just go to the SOURCE pane and look for inlining markers next to function calls.